# jQuery id Selector versus document.getElementById

Tags: jquery

I expected:

```
document.getElementById("audio")
```

and

```
$("#audio")
```

to return the same object but they don't. What am I misunderstanding?

http://jsfiddle.net/uy3sq00n/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are equivalent

```
alert(document.getElementById("audio"));
alert($("#audio")[0]);
```

JQuery wraps the DOM object in its own object

Comment: So it would be standard in query to write the likes of "$("#audio")[0].src = "?

Comment: No.  You almost never need to use [0].  You could set the src like this `$('#audio').attr('src', src);`

Answer (score 2):

Both aren't same as you think. jQuery return j[Query object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)  and document.getElementById return [HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element).

you can get more detail about this if do `console.log`

```
console.log(document.getElementById("audio")); 
console.log($("#audio"));

<audio id="audio">  --> document.getElementById("audio")

Object { 0: <audio#audio>, length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → _display, selector: "#audio" }  --> $("#audio")
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery()` (or `$()`) returns a jQuery object, with all the jQuery added features. `document.getElementById` returns a standard HTML element.